# How to find the table/view names and corresponding projected column names in a SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, parsing

We're building an application where the user chooses data sources and either builds the SQL

1. using our SQL query builder OR
2. pastes an existing SQL into the app.

One of the requirements of this app is to obtain some of the table/view column properties, including data type and size, precision, etc. If the user uses the option #1 SQL query builder, then we will know the column properties by introspecting from the DB; However, if the user chooses option #2, i.e, pasting an existing SQL, then we will need to parse the SQL and then find out the required properties of all the SELECT(projected) columns. The question is, how to achieve this goal of:

1. find out the tables/views and the corresponding projected column names from the pasted SQL.

We use java at the backend and prefer java libraries but are open to other language libraries if none exist in java to do the above 2 features. From [this](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-sql/), I see there are several libraries but I couldn't figure out which of these libraries/tools can help get the table/view names and the corresponding column names so that I can introspect the db and find the required properties.

Although our application works on all Databases, for now, our customers use MySQL and Oracle. So, the libraries should be able to parse these 2 databases, for now.

I realize that I could build a parser for both MySQL and Oracle using ANTLR but I don't know how much time it would take to build a parser for real-world SQL.

Would appreciate pointers on which approach, tools will be faster to get towards the goal.

Our front-end is in React and backend is in Java, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 standard ways:

1 Using dbms_sql.parse + dbms_sql.describe_columns: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/others/dbms_sql-basics-describe_columns-method/

2 execute "explain plan" and select from plan_table:

```
explain plan SET STATEMENT_ID = 'PLAN1' for select * from dual;

select object_type, object_owner, object_name, projection, search_columns, access_predicates, filter_predicates
from plan_table 
where statement_id='PLAN1'
and object_type is not null;
```

Obviously you can combine these methods and also all_tables/all_tab_columns.

In case if you will need to analyze also used user views and their source, you can use dbms_utility.expand_sql_text: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/expand-sql-text-12cr1